# In three dimensional euclidean space, can we take projection of a plane onto a plane

Tags: linear-algebra, euclidean-geometry, projection

*I was reading about projection mapping in linear algebra between finite dimensional vector spaces. There were given a condition that my space should be written as direct sum of two of its subspaces V and W to define projection onto V along W.* **Now my question is**

- we can take projections of x=y plane in yz plane in 3D euclidean geometry, this case after x=y would be precisely yz plane.
- But as per  our definition of projection mapping, R^3 should be writen as direct sum of x=y plane and xz plane, but here is not so.
- Are they means different projections? I mean in euclidean 3D geometry we can take projections of plane onto a plane, but here in the definition of linear algebra about projection we cant take like  this in 3D.
- So are not they denotes same projection?

May be my concepts are not clear at all. Please help me to clear out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dude, you should work on your English. The last two points are completely non-understandable (at least to me).

Comment: @amsmath I hope you are now comfortable in my last two lines. Sorry for the inconvenience caused. If the answer is know to you please submit in answer section. Thanks.

Comment: You might want to take another look at the definition of ”direct sum.”

Comment: @amd sir I cant understand what you want to mean.

Comment: A three-dimensional space cannot be the _direct_ sum of a pair of its two-dimensional subspaces.

Comment: @amd sir please go through my post, I've already mentioned there that by the  definition of projection in linear algebra in 3D space we cannot take  projection of a plane onto a plane, but in undergrad euclidean geometry there were told we can take a projection of a plane onto a plane. So now my question is are they demands different projection rule?

Comment: @amd sir as per I know in linear algebra we read about generalization version of 2D/3D space, then all rules should be same na?